React: Mouse flickering and staring animation
I'm learning react to code a front end for my application.
m canvas looks like this:
 return (
        <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
            <button
                onClick={toggleVisualization}
                style={{
                    marginBottom: "10px",
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    background: isVisualizationVisible ? "#FF4136" : "#007BFF",
                    color: "#FFF",
                    border: "none",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                }}
            >
                {isVisualizationVisible ? "Stop Visualization" : "Start Visualization"}
            </button>
            
            <Stage
                width={window.innerWidth * 0.75}
                height={window.innerHeight}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
                onDblClick={handleDoubleClick}
                style={{ background: "#ddd" }}
            >
                <Layer ref={layerRef}>
                    {isVisualizationVisible && (                        
                        <CanvasTrajectoryVisualizer
                            trajectoryFile="/file.txt"
                            stageWidth={window.innerWidth * 0.75}
                            stageHeight={window.innerHeight}
                            isVisible={isVisualizationVisible}
                            
                        />
                    )}
                </Layer>     
                <Layer>
                 other things like grid go here
                </Layer>
          </Stage>
        </div>

The animation works, but then I kinda need to move the mouse over the stage and stop. Then, otherwise, the flickering starts.
Sorry, if this is a known problem or I failed to explain myself correctly. I still hope, though, that someone may direct me in the right direction.
Here is a video showing my problem:
